# How can I specify the memory for google cloud functions emulator?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Is there a way to specify the memory used by firebase functions when running locally through the emulator? I know it can be done in google cloud (which I have done and can see my functions are working) but im not able to see anything in the documentation and I suspect low mem is causing issues in performance when running locally.

Comment: The way in which you set the memory is [in the code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation)? `const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '1GB'
}
`

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not publicly documented and we can assume that this is not currently possible. You can file a Feature Request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). With every feature request, the Engineering team has more visibility of your needs and they can work on them accordingly to the impact on the users. This is the importance to look first for an existing one. I have searched but not found any, so I think the best way to proceed in this case is to create a new one. Please as much details as possible about how would you like to work this feature and if you found any workaround, so, the community in the PIT can implement it.